# COS Setting keyboard-interactive

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems-ensemble

Is there any config setting in Net.SSH.Session that will let you set keyboard-interactive I don't see any option to set this in class(%Net.SSH.Session)?

http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?APP=1&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Net.SSH.Session

```
s ssh=##class(%Net.SSH.Session).%New()  
w "Connect to "_url_"/"_dir,!
s sc=ssh.Connect(url,port)
s sc=ssh.AuthenticateWithUsername(un,pwd)
```

Comment: What do you mean by keyboard-interactive, you expect to get some kind of telnet over ssh, with a possibility to enter some commands?

Comment: In Java I have used JSch and there was a setConfig class I was just looking for that class in COS.'//create object'.
'var jsch = new JSch();'

'jsch.setConfig('StrictHostKeyChecking','no');'

'var session = jsch.getSession(un,url,22);'
'session.setPassword(pwd);'
'session.setTimeout(20000);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Read command http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_cread

```
r "URL: ",url
r "Dir: ",dir
w "Connect to "_url_"/"_dir,!
s ssh=##class(%Net.SSH.Session).%New()  
s sc=ssh.Connect(url,port)
s sc=ssh.AuthenticateWithUsername(un,pwd)
```